# pass from interface a to interface b with android

Tags: android

Hello
I'm beginning with android development
I created two interfaces, the first a.xml and the second b.xml.

In the first I have an ImageButton. My goal is to switch to interface b when the user clicks on the ImageButton (button.setonclicklistner).

How can I use the activity and intent to navigate between the interfaces
(I have one file java pg.java 
the intent function parameters ActivtyA.class. I don't inderstand it (I haven't a file pg.class)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is pseudo-code, so don't take it as-is, but adapt it for your needs.

```
public ActivityA extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

   onCreate(...){
      ...
      setContentView(R.layout.a);


      ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.myImageButton);
      imageButton.setOnClickListener(this);
   }

   protected void onClickListener(View v){
      Intent switchToActivityBIntent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
      startActivity(switchToActivityBIntent);
   }

   ...

}
```

On ActivityB:

```
public ActivityB extends Activity{

   onCreate(...){
      ...
      setContentView(R.layout.b);
   }
}
```

If you're beginning with Android development, the [Android Application Fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html) are a must.

You may also want to read by blog post about how to add click listeners declaratively to buttons: http://blog.js-development.com/2010/11/android-attaching-clicklisteners.html

Answer (score 0):

You need two `Activity` classes, `ActivityA.java` and `ActivityB.java`.
Then, in `ActivityA.java`, create the code below in the behaviour that you want to be launched:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
ActivityA.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question very much.
If you just want to show a new user interface based on b.xml, you could simply call `setContentView(R.layout.b)` .
If you want to start another activity whose user interface is based on b.xml; well, generally, in your button.setonclicklistner method, you can do something like this:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
ActivityA.this.startActivity(intent);
```

Of course, you need to write a class named ActivityB first.
You can find more about Intent in the SDK document. Hope it helps.